# Finding a keyword from a text file and printing the value in python2.7

Tags: text, readfile

I have a text file containing following format:

```
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen : (level 0)
    X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Messages_Alert_States : ! (level 1)
    X_0_Gui_Menu_600_Menu_Status : i (level 1)
        X_0_Gui_Menu_650_Menu_Status_Version : Version info (level 2)
        X_0_Gui_Menu_610_Menu_Status_System : System info (level 2)
        X_0_Gui_Menu_670_Menu_Status_Media : Media A/B info (level 2)
        X_0_Gui_Menu_680_Menu_Status_USB : USB info (level 2)
```

I would like to search for a keyword like "X_0_Gui_Menu_680_Menu_Status_USB" from a function and if found get the value `level 2` and `USB info` I came up with following code but for some reason it returns a empty string.

```
def page_level_and_gui_name(keyword):
    global new_dir_name
    os.chdir("..")
    os.chdir("..")
    os.chdir("..")
    with open("gui_page_variables_and_names", "r") as page_level_and_gui_name:
        level = ""
        gui_name = ""
        for line in page_level_and_gui_name:
            if keyword in line:
                level = re.findall(r"\((.*?)\)",line)
                gui_name = re.findall(r" \: (.*?) \(",line)
        print "       > level : " + str(level)
        print "       > gui-name : " + str(gui_name)
    os.chdir("~Gui_analysis")
    os.chdir(new_dir_name)
    os.chdir("Data_in_each_page")
```

MODIFIED CODE:

To make sure its not the problem of directory switching I copied the text file containing the string in run time to the folder where execution happens and use the file from there yet the script doesn't go into the loop `if keyword in line:` too !

```
global new_dir_name
shutil.copy("file.txt", "~Gui_analysis/"+ new_dir_name + "/Data_in_each_page")
with open("file.txt", "r") as page_level_and_gui_name:
    level = ""
    gui_name = ""
    for line in page_level_and_gui_name:
        if keyword in line:
            level = re.findall(r"\((.*?)\)",line)
            gui_name = re.findall(r" \: (.*?) \(",line)
    print "       > level : " + str(level)
    print "       > keyword : " + keyword
    print "       > gui-name : " + str(gui_name)
```

But this too doesn't make any difference over the issue

I am not sure what is the real problem in the code. Why it prints an empty string !

UPDATE:

I today figured out the function is not able to get the correct keyword into the `if function`, but when I print the keyword I could see the correct keyword in the same function outside it but not into the if function.

But when I hard code an example keyword like:

```
keyword = "X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Set"
```

Then it prints correctly as

```
   > level : ['level 2']
   > keyword : X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Set
   > gui-name : ['SET']
```

I am not sure what exactly is the issue here

But when I call it directly in the function. This is what I get as output

```
  X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
       > level : 
       > keyword : X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
       > gui-name :
```

Comment: your code is "almost ok", you are probably no loading the right file.

Comment: @elyase I cross checked the file by printing the line from `for line in page_level_and_gui_name:` it prints all the line from the file. But it doesn't go inside the `if` condition. I also tried to rip off the tabs in between the text file. But that too is not helping me out...

Comment: I tested your code and it works(prints the expected two lines), I came to the same conclusion as @trevolution.

Comment: If it's not going inside the if statement, the `keyword` variable probably has an error in it. Check the case and spelling of your keyword to make sure it's exactly the same as in the file.

Comment: @jyapayne I clearly checked the keyword. It's exactly what it is in the example I have given. I can update the question with more lines of the file to be sure...If its a strange error I am only facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after hours of trail and error. The main issue was with `keyword` I had to strip it before comparing with the line in the text file `keyword = keyword.strip()` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might have to do with all of the directory switching you're doing.

Hard to say without knowing your file structure. Assuming your txt file is in the current directory...

This is a stripped down version of what I *think* you're trying to accomplish:

```
input_file = 'input.txt'
keyword = 'X_0_Gui_Menu_680_Menu_Status_USB'

def page_level_and_gui_name(input_file, keyword):
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            if keyword in line: 
                level = line.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
                gui_name = line.split(':')[1].split('(')[0]
                return info,gui_name
```

I would use this and take care of finding the file somewhere else. (all of the os.chdir() )

This example only finds the first instance but could be easily extended to find all instances and store them in a list or something.

UPDATE: 
The following produced expected results for me:

```
>>> with open("gui_page_variables_and_names", "r") as page_level_and_gui_name:
...         level = ""
...         gui_name = ""
...         for line in page_level_and_gui_name:
...             if keyword in line:
...                 level = re.findall(r"\((.*?)\)",line)
...                 gui_name = re.findall(r" \: (.*?) \(",line)
...         print "       > level : " + str(level)
...         print "       > gui-name : " + str(gui_name)
... 
       > level : ['level 2']
       > gui-name : ['USB info']
```

Can you share the code you are using to cross check?

Comment: I cross checked if I am loading correct file by printing the lines after ` for line in page_level_and_gui_name:` it correctly prints all the line from the file but some how it doesn't find the keyword inside it. I also cross checked if I get the correct `keyword` it too is fine. The strange thing is I can see both the keywords when I print the `keyword` and the `lines from the text file`

Comment: Didn't look right as a comment, please see update.

Comment: I think you have commented exactly code which I have posted. I tried to check the code which you have answered unfortunately. I have exactly the same issue. When I print all the lines it prints the matching line too. To verify the file path is correct. But when I try to print only the value from `keyword` and `gui_name` it doesn't unfortunately. It seems really strange. I couldn't find the issue.

Comment: I have also updated the actual code I use

Comment: I hope you could see the updated version

Comment: if it's printing an empty string, the value of `level` and `gui_name` must not be getting set.  Try adding `print line` after the `if keyword in line` statement, see if you condition is ever being met.

Comment: As mentioned in my question problem. It doesn't even get to the if statement. Thats the real isssue. `re.findall` is not able to find the strings. I also to be sure if it is not file shifting problem copied the text file in run time to the folder where execution happens. I could also see the file getting copied during run time and execute it from the same directory. Yet no success!

Comment: So to clarify, you are saying `if keyword in line` is false for all lines? Can you show me the actual `"file.txt"` and `keyword` you are using?

Comment: The actual file.txt is nothing but the same as I have posted. I can send you the file you can check it too. But I have no idea how to send you the file over here.